# Доступ к переменным в классах-представлениях

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

У меня есть такая ссылка

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/var/cea4067b96/
```

и класс-представление

```
class MyView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['data'] = 2

        return context
```

Как получить доступ к переменной `var` в `get_context_data`?

Comment: зависит от того как у вас сконфигурирован URL, если там есть перменная var, то `kwargs['var']` или `kwargs.get('var')`

Comment: так url(r'^var/(?P<var>[^\W_]{10})/$', а если нет переменной?

Comment: должно сработать, посмотрите дебаггером или хотя бы обычным print. Здесь больше информации: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: да, kwargs['var'] содержит значение. А если такой url(r'^var/([^\W_]{10})/$', и нет переменной?

Comment: тогда не будет переменной. В доке написано что `P<name>` обьявляет переменную

Comment: Спасибо большое